# Fusion Charts Show Percentage as centerLabel in Doughnut Chart

Tags: jquery, fusioncharts

With Fusion Charts script, I'm easily able to show chart labels as percentages. However, I need to show values on the labels and show percentages in the center of the doughnut chart.

The Fusion Charts API does not appear to cover this option. It appears that $value and $label are the only variables available.

Is it possible to do this?

Here is some jquery for the setup if it looks like I'm missing something obvious:

```
$.each(jsonDataPoints, function (index, obj) {
        var hoverText = obj.label + " (" + obj.value + ")";
        //obj.toolText = hoverText; //This sets the text to display when a pie chart is hovered.
        //obj.displayValue = hoverText; //This sets the chart labels.
        obj.displayValue = obj.value; //This sets the chart labels.
        obj.centerLabel = obj.percentValue;//percentValue is not an object. Just a guess
    });

    var doughnutChart = new FusionCharts({
        type: 'doughnut2D',
        renderAt: containerId,
        registerWithJS: '1',
        dataFormat: 'json',
        "width": "100%",
        "height": "100%",
        dataSource: {
            "chart": {
                "paletteColors": "#0075c2,#1aaf5d,#f2c500,#f45b00,#8e0000",
                "bgColor": "#ffffff",
                "showBorder": "0",
                "use3DLighting": "0",
                "showShadow": "0",
                "enableSmartLabels": "0",
                "startingAngle": "310",
                "showLabels": "0",
                "showPercentValues": "1",
                "showLegend": "1",
                "legendShadow": "0",
                "legendBorderAlpha": "0",
                "defaultCenterLabel": "...",
                "centerLabel": "$value",
                "centerLabelBold": "1",
                "showTooltip": "1",
                "decimals": "0",
                "captionFontSize": "14",
                "subcaptionFontSize": "14",
                "subcaptionFontBold": "0",
                "useDataPlotColorForLabels": "1",
                "labelDistance": "-20",
                "baseFontSize": "13",
            },
            "data": jsonDataPoints
        }
    });

    doughnutChart.render();
```

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon the answer to this by scanning through the fusioncharts.js source code. The value is $percentValue.

All that was required was to set "centerLabel" : "$percentValue

```
"centerLabel" : "$percentValue
```

This value is set inside the "_parseValues" function in fusioncharts.js

Answer (score 0):

You can use the $percentValue to show the value in percentage

```
    {
  "chart": {
    "defaultCenterLabel": "Total revenue: $60K",
    "centerLabel": "$percentValue"
  }
}
```

Reference code -

```
 FusionCharts.ready(function() {
  var revenueChart = new FusionCharts({
    type: 'doughnut2d',
    renderAt: 'chart-container',
    width: '550',
    height: '450',
    dataFormat: 'json',
    dataSource: {
      "chart": {
        "caption": "Split of Revenue by Product Categories",
        "subCaption": "Last year",
        "numberPrefix": "$",
        "bgColor": "#ffffff",
        "startingAngle": "310",
        "showLegend": "1",
        
        // Configure centerlabel in percentage
        "defaultCenterLabel": "Total revenue: $64.08K",
        "centerLabel": "$percentValue",
        "centerLabelBold": "1",
        "showTooltip": "0",
        "labelFontColor": "#ffffff",
        "decimals": "0",
        "theme": "fusion",
        "valuePosition": "inside",
        "minAngleForValue": "75",
        "enablesmartLabel": "0"

      },
      "data": [{
          "label": "Food",
          "value": "28504"
        },
        {
          "label": "Apparels",
          "value": "14633"
        },
        {
          "label": "Electronics",
          "value": "10507"
        },
        {
          "label": "Household",
          "value": "4910"
        }
      ]
    }
  }).render();
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7wx2eL9y/1/)